# Getting information from classes to run in an app

Tags: java, android, class

So far I have just been putting all my code in one main Activity class. I am now trying to improve this and have different classes.

I am making a very simple app that is like a story.There are 8 pages and 4 characters. Each character has an image, a button with their name and a textView. When you click their button their text is shown.

I have made a class for each character and in this I have put all the methods relating to that character in there. ie,

```
public void johnSpeak1 (View view) {
   johnText1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
   markText1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
}
```

This should mean when the John button is pressed his text becomes visible and the other persons disappears.

It works fine when I had it all in the main activity class but now I have put it in it's own class my app just closes when I run it and press the button.

I have declared all the buttons and `textviews` in the main activity. In the `oncreate` on the main activity I have given all the `findviewbyID` for the first page and also set the textViews to invisible.

Everything I have learnt so far has been from an Udemy video which was great but didn't ever mention classes!!

I have set the other classes I have made to `extends mainActivity`

What I have done so far could all be garbage. I have been trying to do it on my own looking on google for help but I seem to be stumped on this.

Thanks for any advice!

BTW I am using android studio

Danny

Answer (score 0):

First: Always share your error log for quick and clear answer please.

Second: I think your problem is that some view is null in your activity. You can find out in view>toolwindows>logcat, after app crash you will see a list of errors, some part of them has links that lead you to the error cause!

EDIT:
for example you create a class for each character:

```
public class John extends LinearLayout
{
    Context context;
    public John(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        init();            
    }

    public John(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public John(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }
    TextView dialog;
    private void init()
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.john_layout, this);
        dialog = view.findViewById(R.id.dialog);
    }

    public void setShowHideDialog(boolean mustShow)
    {
        if(mustShow)
            dialog.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        else 
            dialog.setVisibility(GONE);
    }
}
```

in john_layout xml put ImageView and TextView and set them with your image and dialog of your character

Then in your Activity xml add john_layout like this:

```
<John android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/ch_john"/>
```

And at last in your activity use John this way:

```
final John john = findViewById(R.id.ch_john);
    john.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mark.setShowHideDialog(false);
            john.setShowHideDialog(true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, the logcat says could not find method in parent or ancestor context. I am very new to Java and not sure what this means. As I said I have never used classes before. So I am not exactly sure where to put what.